# Android Browser produces unexpected behavior with Overflow-y: auto

Tags: android, jquery, css, user-interface, overflow

**I'm trying to achieve a scroll when a table overflows a parent:**

```
<div class="main_container">
<form id="list_wrapper">
<table>
    <tbody>
           <tr><td>HELLO</td></tr>
           <tr><td>HELLO</td></tr>
           <tr><td>HELLO</td></tr>
           <tr><td>HELLO</td></tr>
           <tr><td>HELLO</td></tr>
           <tr><td>HELLO</td></tr>
           <tr><td>HELLO</td></tr>
           <tr><td>HELLO</td></tr>
     </tbody>
   </table>
 </form>
</div>

//JQuery that will dynamically resize rows depending on how many rows there are.
<script type="text/javascript>
setTimeout(function(){
    var totalRowHeight = $("tr").height() * $("tr").length;    
    $("form#list_wrapper").css("height", "" + totalRowHeight + "");
},1);​
</script>
```

See [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bigthyme/CL3Fk/1) for a demonstration!

Interestingly enough, when opening this link on my Droid X browser (version: 2.3.4), the table still overflows but does not scroll. I want the Android to replicate the behavior that is seen when opening the link via desktop browsers.

**Note**: I've tested this link in IOS browsers including Safari and Chrome and those work great.

Comment: Better to post your code here and let us see it. Include the link at least - so that people can just click it.

Comment: thanks @nickhar, I will do this from now on.